# Ethers.js not detecting Contract emitting event

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have contract factory that creates a new contract and it emits an event called `Created` when a new `FundMe` contract is created:

```
contract FundFactory {
    // Events
    event Created(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed assetAddress,
        address indexed fundAddress
    );

    // Variables
    address public i_owner;
    FundMe[] public s_funds;

    constructor() {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
    }

function createFundMe(
        uint256 lockTime,
        address assetAddress,
        address assetAddress2,
    ) public returns (address) {
        FundMe fundMe = new FundMe(lockTime, assetAddress, assetAddress2);
        s_funds.push(fundMe);
        emit Created(msg.sender, assetAddress, address(fundMe));
    }
```

I'm trying to access the newly created `FundMe` contract, so I'm trying to get the  address from the event that gets emitted. I have tried to listen for the event by using ether's `provider.on` function, but I haven't been able to get that to fire. Here is my code for that:

```
await deploy("FundFactory", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [],
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: networkConfig[chainId].blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    const fundFactory = await ethers.getContract("FundFactory")

    const createFundTx = await fundFactory.createFundMe(
        locktime,
        assetAddress,
        assetAddress2
    )

    await createFundTx.wait(1)

    const filter = {
        address: fundFactory.address,
        topics: [utils.id("Created(address,address,address)")],
    }
    const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider()
    provider.on(filter, (owner, assetAddress, fundAddress) => {
        console.log("hello")
        console.log(owner, assetAddress, fundAddress)
    })
```

The deploy goes through without erroring, but not only am I not able to print out the actual contents of the event,the `console.log(hello)` doesn't even get fired... I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could it be because I'm using the hardhat local environment `yarn hardhat deploy`?

Comment: I also tried `fundFactory.on("Created", (owner, assetAddress, fundAddress) => {
        console.log("hello")
        console.log(owner, assetAddress, fundAddress)
    })` but that was just as unsuccessful as the other way to listen to the event

Comment: Did you check how to get internal transactions events in ethers.js?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by this, would my event be an internal event?